# Multiple problems with alsamixer after opening up laptop (no problems in other OSs)

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, bios, alsamixer

This randomly started happening today. Yesterday I opened up my laptop to clean it out. I also disconnected the CMOS battery cable by mistake.

When I open `alsamixer` in a terminal, the following things happen when I try to control the channels:

- Controlling the 'PCM' channel is the only way for me to change the volume.
- Using the up/down arrow keys when selecting the master channel, it changes the numbers but doesn't actually change the volume. Even weirder: controlling the master volume mutes it instead. It also mutes the headphone channel, but not the speaker channel.
- Unmuting the master channel by pressing 'M' doesn't bring the audio back. To do that, I have to press Fn+F1, which is bound to `pactl set-sink-mute 0 toggle` in sxhkdrc (using bspwm).
- Using Fn+F2/F3 (bound to `pactl set-sink-volume 0 -/+ 5%`) to decrease/increase changes the master channel but doesn't change the audio, but also doesn't mute it.
- (un)Muting the headphone channel doesn't do anything to the audio. Increasing/decreasing the headphone channel doesn't change the volume.
- Muting the master channel also mutes the headphone channel, but unmuting the master channel doesn't unmute the headhpone channel.
- I can't get the speakers to work at all.
- When I lower the master channel using the function keys all the way to 0, the headphone channel goes down as well. When the headphone channel gets to 0, it mutes only the right channel (wtf?).

Everything works in Windows (I did have a problem with audio drivers in Windows but a reboot fixed it) and in Ubuntu 18.10 on a USB live stick. I'm on a laptop (Lenovo Legion Y520) running Arch Linux. According to alsamixer I'm using the `HDA Intel PCH` soundcard and `Realtek ALC233` chip.

EDIT: I saw in `pavucontrol` that I have two audio outputs: Headphones and Speakers. Next to speakers, it says 'unavailable'.

EDIT: dmesg: https://pastebin.com/YUr4MyDf

output of `ls /proc/asound/card*/codec*`:

> /proc/asound/card0/codec#0
>
> /proc/asound/card0/codec#2

Comment: I just tried that and now only my left headphones work. wtf? EDIT: I rebooted again and now both sides work. Weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HdaIntelSoundHowto#Playing_with_probe_mask

I still have an error in dmesg: `snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: control 2:0:0:PCM Playback Volume:0 is already present`, but I don't experience any problems.

Answer (score 3):

You are seeing the `pulse` plugin control, which only has a single volume control. Try using <kbd>F6</kbd> to access the hardware control(s) of your sound card(s).

However, since you are now running Pulseaudio as your main audio system (possibly you rebooted for the first time because of the cleaning, and it's the consequence of some update you did a longer time ago?), I'd recommend to leave `alsamixer` alone, and use `pavucontrol` or the sound settings of your Desktop (if you are using one) instead.

Using both can misconfigure the intermediate amplifiers, causing clipping and sound distortion.

As you already played around it with, you may to have to use `alsamixer` once to restore everything to a good state (e.g. unmute accidentally muted nodes, etc.)

**Edit**

Your codec is properly recognized:

```
[    3.845593] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
...
[    3.883968] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC233: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[    3.883969] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    3.883970] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    3.883971] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    3.883972] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[    3.883973] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x19
[    3.883974] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x12
```

but soon after, something fails fails:

```
[   16.496761] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: azx_get_response timeout, switching to polling mode: last cmd=0x202f2d00
[   17.500096] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, disabling MSI: last cmd=0x202f2d00
[   18.510492] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: azx_get_response timeout, switching to single_cmd mode: last cmd=0x202f2d00
```

and then things start to look funny:

```
[  138.168712] azx_single_send_cmd: 14 callbacks suppressed
[  391.888726] azx_single_send_cmd: 34 callbacks suppressed
[  403.161786] azx_single_send_cmd: 114 callbacks suppressed
[  447.315584] azx_single_send_cmd: 46 callbacks suppressed
[  514.846522] azx_single_send_cmd: 70 callbacks suppressed
```

So, guess: While cleaning your laptop (unless you did something else you didn't tell us about), you caused electrostatic discharge, and/or the battery cable you disconnected by accident touched something it shouldn't, and now something relating to sound card/codec communication doesn't work properly.

This will be difficult to properly diagnose and fix. You can play around with `hda-verb` and look at the contents of the codec file, and see if you can further narrow down the problems, but to do this, you need to read up on how this stuff works. It's not something we can remotely debug with a Q&A.

I don't know why it works in Windows and doesn't work in Linux. Possibly Windows initializes the hardware differently.

Comment: This is what I'm seeing in alsamixer: https://i.imgur.com/jpXgwrU.png. When I press F6, the only choices I have are 'default' , 'hda intel pch', and 'enter device name...'. Changing between the first two do nothing, do I have different device? How can I check? Today when I booted for the first time, only the left channel of my heapdhones worked again. Previously that was fixed with a reboot but I've rebooted three times now and nothing changes. Nothing in alsamixer or pulseaudio indicates the right channel being muted.

Comment: I also can't use pavucontrol on its own, because it only has one slider which adjusts the master volume, which of course doesn't do anything to the volume. Is there a way to reset everything? Delete all config files to reset all sliders or something?

Comment: Booting to my Ubuntu live USB (where everything works) and then rebooting to my arch installation fixed the right headphone channel. I have no clue what to do here.

Comment: `hda intel pch` is your hardware. If you don't see controls, possibly the Intel Soundcard can't find the codec. Have a close look at `dmesg` after boot; if you don't understand edit, upload it into pastebin etc. and edit question with link. Also, edit question with output of `ls /proc/asound/card*/codec*`.

Comment: edited question.

Comment: "I don't know why it works in Windows and doesn't work in Linux. Possibly Windows initializes the hardware differently." What's weirder is that everything works fine in Ubuntu, but not my arch installation, making me think that everything is software-related.

Comment: Here's the output of `dmesg` when booting from an Ubuntu live USB: https://pastebin.com/qS6GYqws

Comment: If it's software related, the place to look is in the kernel (though the Intel HDA soundcard *should* be sufficiently stable). Ubuntu is 4.18.0, Arch is 4.18.16 (custom built?). Try a 4.18.0 kernel on Arch and see what happens. If it works, file a regression bug on the kernel bugtracker.

Comment: I did `journalctl | grep 'single_cmd mode'` and found that the first time I got those errors were Nov 01, but I cleaned out my laptop the day after.

Comment: Kernel is default arch kernel, not custom built.

Comment: The question remains why it has to fall back to single command mode on Arch, but doesn't on Ubuntu ... And if the Codec single command mode is a red herring, the question is what else doesn't work.

Comment: Does it have something to with the fact that Ubuntu is installed on a USB stick, while arch is on an SSD?

Comment: This is incredibly weird: I booted my laptop without my headphones in (I always boot with headphones in otherwise) and my speakers worked. I then rebooted with headphones in to check if something changed and found that the dmesg errors are gone, and I can change the volume using the master channel like befoore. There is still something bugged, though: when adjusting the volume with the function keys, which are bound to `pactl set-sink-volume 0 +/- 5%`, there's about a 1-2 second delay before it actually changes the volume. Is this a problem with pactl? I didn't have this problem before.

Comment: There's no delay when pavucontrol is open.

Comment: The delay seems to be gone, meaning pretty much all my issues have been fixed without me doing anything. I have no clue how this happened.

Comment: This is weird: today I booted and didn't have sound, so I checked `dmesg` and I found an error that said something like `no codecs found`. I booted into Ubuntu and it said the same thing. When I then booted into Windows the problems went away and the codec was found again :/

Comment: My money is still on "static discharge etc. screwed up a hardware circuit somewhere, now it's acting randomly and sometimes works, sometimes doesn't".

Comment: But why does it always seem to work in Windows but not in linux? I rebooted arch like 10 times, ubuntu twice, and then I went to Windows and everything was fixed...

Comment: Again: Windows uses a different hardware initialization/access sequence, which doesn't cause the problematic hardware part to act up. (But all this is a guess, and hard to confirm).

Comment: Right, guess I'll have to live with it then :/ Thanks for all the help!